# Determining if Cancel Button pressed where InputBox variable declared as Double

Tags: excel, vba

I have my variable declared as a double so I can perform mathematical operations on it.

I am trying to determine when the cancel button is pressed.

```
Dim thckmax As Double

thckmax = InputBox("What is the maximum nominal thickness?", "Enter Max Nominal Thickness Measurement")
If thckmax = 0 Then
     GoTo Line3
End If

thckmin = InputBox("What is the minimum nominal thickness?", "Enter Min Nominal Thickness Measurement")
If thckmin = 0 Then
     GoTo Line3
End If
thcknom = (thckmax + thckmin) / 2
Worksheets(1).Range("C" & cols + 2).Value = thcknom
.
.
.
Line3: ...
```

I know I used `GoTo`. It was a quick and easy fix to get the code up and running.

I get Run-Time error 13 type mismatch. I have also tried `CDbl(...)`,`StrPtr(...)`,`IsEmpty(...)` and instead of setting them equal to zero I have also tried

```
If thckmax = "" Then
    GoTo Line3
End If`
```

I cannot get anything to work as far as determining if cancel was pressed and going to `Line3:`.

**All posts I found indicate the declared variable as a string, mine is a double.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if user select cancel InputBox VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264814/how-to-detect-if-user-select-cancel-inputbox-vba-excel)

Comment: @sous2817 Unfortunately that one declares the variable as a string. Like I said above mine is declared a double so I can perform mathematical operations on it.

Comment: 'Quick and easy fixes' usually cause issues

Comment: when you debug the procedure, what is the value of `thckmax` ?

Comment: @A.Jones perhaps see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16061740/9245853) for how to use `InputBox` and validate that the input is numeric before attempting to use it. Entering non-numeric values in the code you have will throw the type mismatch error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble with InputBoxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061562/trouble-with-inputboxes)

Comment: @Damian It does not return a value when I hit the cancel button. When i `Debug.Print thckmax` the immediate window remains blank and it throws the runtime error if I break it before it enters the if statement. However when I enter a value it shows up as the value I entered in the immediate window.

Comment: @BigBen Unfortunately that has no examples with variables set up as doubles. I have thoroughly searched this site for a good 3 hours and have found only ones that have the variables set up as strings, and that is why I asked this question.

Comment: As I said [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55027629/inputbox-confusing-decimal-entries-with-strings/55027742?noredirect=1#comment96840110_55027742), the function returns a `String`. You need to capture the result into a `String`. Coercing it into a `Double` without any validation is literally asking for a type mismatch error.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I tried what you suggested earlier however as a VBA beginner I did not quite understand what you were meaning.

Comment: Yeah, well, it's hard to explain these things in a little comment box. See the answer below, and note how the `InputBox` result is captured into a `String` that is then validated to be a number, and the `Double` only gets assigned if the `String` is confirmed to be a numeric value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this to test whether or not the input box was canceled and if it is numeric.

```
Dim thckmaxTest As String
Dim thckmax As Double

thckmaxTest = InputBox("What is the maximum nominal thickness?", "Enter Max Nominal Thickness Measurement")
If thckmaxTest <> vbNullString and IsNumeric(thckmaxTest) then thckmax = CDbl(thckmaxTest)
If thckmax = 0 Then
     GoTo Line3
End If

Dim thckminTest As String
Dim thckmin As Double 

thckminTest = InputBox("What is the minimum nominal thickness?", "Enter Min Nominal Thickness Measurement")
If thckminTest <> vbNullString and IsNumeric(thckmibTest) then thckmin = CDbl(thckminTest)
If thckmin = 0 Then
     GoTo Line3
End If
thcknom = (thckmax + thckmin) / 2
Worksheets(1).Range("C" & cols + 2).Value = thcknom
```

Answer (score 4):

As is noted in [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/inputbox-function), the `InputBox` function returns a string.

How then, you may ask, can you sometimes store the return value from an `InputBox` to an integer value? Because of implicit coercion. Basically, if you try to store a value in an incompatible variable, VBA attempts to coerce the value to the right data type. If you try to store a `string` value into a `Double` variable, VBA attempts to coerce the string into the right data type. This occurs whether you use `InputBox` or a hard-coded string. For example, the following snippets are equivalent:

```
Dim x as Double
x = "5"
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim x As Double
x = InputBox("Enter a number")
' user enters 5
```

When using `InputBox`, you of course have no control over whether the user enters valid input. Which is why (as @Dude_Scott mentions), you should store user input into a string, and then make sure you have the right value.

If the user clicks **Cancel** in the inputbox, the empty string is returned (as per documentation above). Since the empty string can't be implicitly coerced to a double, an error is generated. It's the same thing that would happen if the user entered "apples" in the InputBox.

As @Dude_Scott notes, you should use `IsNumeric` (or something similar) to make sure that the user input is what you need. However, you don't need to include a check for a null or empty string (since IsNumeric returns False for those values). So you really just need something like this:

```
Public Sub foo()
    Dim xDouble As Double, xString As String

    xString = InputBox("Enter a number")

    If IsNumeric(xString) Then
        xDouble = CDbl(xString)
        MsgBox xDouble
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid number"
    End If
End Sub
```

For more information about coercion, see the following Microsoft articles:

- [Conversions Between Strings and Other Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/conversions-between-strings-and-other-types)
- [Implicit and Explicit Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/implicit-and-explicit-conversions)

Comment: This is an accidental and undocumented quirk, but if you need to be able to tell a legit empty string from a cancelled inputbox, then `StrPtr(xString)` would return `0` if the inputbox was cancelled, and a non-zero value for an okayed inputbox with an empty string input.

Comment: This was extremely helpful in my understanding of what @MathieuGuindon was trying to explain to me earlier. Thank you!

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42016288/9990662) for a good description of `StrPtr`.

Comment: I like the irony of `MsgBox xDouble`... .which is implicitly `MsgBox CStr(xDouble)` ;-)

Answer (score 3):

> *All others I have found indicate the declared variable as a string, mine is a DOUBLE*

You can't have a `Double`. The function returns a `String`, and you can't change that. Using a `Double` to capture the result **will** cause problems sooner or later.

What I was trying to explain in a comment box earlier, is that there's a possibility that `0` might be a valid input, so immediately converting the input into a `Double` is preventing you from being able to tell cancellation from a legit `0` - regardless of the type mismatch error that's guaranteed to happen whenever the resut isn't numeric.

As other answers show, this involves quite a bit of plumbing: enough to warrant being pulled into its own dedicated wrapper function.

The problem is that functions return *one* value, so you can return a `Double` and pick a specific "magic value" to mean "input was cancelled", but that's a poor practice.

A better way is to make the wrapper function return a `Boolean`, and leverage a `ByRef` parameter to return the result - a function like this returns `False` if the user cancels the prompt, `True` if the prompt was not cancelled, and `outResult` will be either `0` for a non-numeric input, or the input converted to a `Double`:

```
Public Function TryGetDoubleInput( _
    ByVal prompt As String, _
    ByVal title As String, _
    ByVal default As String, _
    ByRef outResult As Double) _
As Boolean
    Dim result As String
    result = VBA.Interaction.InputBox(prompt, title, default)
    TryGetDoubleInput = StrPtr(result) <> 0 'return false if cancelled
    If IsNumeric(result) Then outResult = CDbl(result)
End Function
```

Can be used like this:

```
Dim value As Double
If TryGetDoubleInput("Enter a numeric value:", "Prompt", "0.00", value) Then
    If value = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You entered either 0 or a non-numeric value"
    Else
        MsgBox "You entered " & CStr(value) ' note the irony
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "You cancelled the prompt"
End If
```

Now if you need to treat invalid values differently than `0` (i.e. if `0` is a legit input), consider throwing an error:

```
Public Function TryGetDoubleInput( _
    ByVal prompt As String, _
    ByVal title As String, _
    ByVal default As String, _
    ByRef outResult As Double) _
As Boolean
    Dim result As String
    result = VBA.Interaction.InputBox(prompt, title, default)
    If StrPtr(result) = 0 Then Exit Function 'return false if cancelled

    If IsNumeric(result) Then 
        outResult = CDbl(result)
        TryGetDoubleInput = True
    Else
        Err.Raise 555, "TryGetDoubleInput", "Non-numeric input is invalid."
    End If
End Function
```

And now you can use error handling to handle invalid inputs, and you can now tell a legit `0` from a cancelled inputbox from an arbitrary invalid input:

```
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Dim value As Double
If TryGetDoubleInput("Enter a numeric value:", "Prompt", "0.00", value) Then
    MsgBox "You entered " & CStr(value) ' note the irony
Else
    MsgBox "You cancelled the prompt"
End If

Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description ' "Non-numeric input is invalid."
```

Comment: I do wonder why nobody suggested `application.inputbox("What is the maximum nominal thickness?",Type:=1)`...

Comment: @GSerg `Application.InputBox` is tied to the Excel object model. `VBA.InputBox` works in any host. But yeah.